# How can I disconnect and reconnect to new Bluetooth device automatically?

Tags: android, bluetooth, reconnect

I need to send a message to Bluetooth device (phone), and after that disconnect and send the message to another phone.

I tried the Bluetooth chat but there seems to be a conflict when I reconnect automatically.